# Detect when OpenFileDialog returns a downloaded URL/URI

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, openfiledialog

I'm using OpenFileDialog (.Net Framework 4, Windows 10) and I've noticed that it will allow the user to specify a URL as the file name (e.g., http://somewebsite/picture.jpg). This is very useful for my application, so I don't intend to disable it. The way it works is downloading the file into the user's temp directory and returning the temporary file name in the dialog's Filename property. This is nice, except for the fact that the user starts to build up garbage in his/her temp directory.

I would like to tell when a file was downloaded by the OpenFileDialog class (as opposed to a previously existing file), so I can clean up by deleting the file after use. I could check if the file's directory is the temp directory, but that's not very good since the user might have downloaded the file him/herself.

I've tried intercepting the FileOK event and inspect the Filename property to see if it is an HTTP/FTP URI, but despite what the documentation says ("Occurs when the user selects a file name by either clicking the Open button of the OpenFileDialog") it is fired *after* the file is downloaded, so I don't get access to the URL: the Filename property already has the temporary file name.

EDIT: This is an example of what I'like to do:

```
Dim dlgOpenFile As New System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog

If dlgOpenFile.ShowDialog(Me) <> Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then Return

''//do some stuff with dlgOpenFile.Filename

If dlgOpenFile.WasAWebResource Then
    Dim finfo = New IO.FileInfo(dlgOpenFile.Filename)
    finfo.Delete()
End If
```

In this example, I've imagined a property to dlgOpenFile "WasAWebResource" that would tell me if the file was downloaded or originally local. If it's the first case, I'll delete it.

Comment: can you please provide some code? because by only description it is hard to help you

Comment: There's not much to it. I added some example. I hope it helps.

Comment: It is just a broken UI problem.  OpenFileDialog is quite less than ideal to navigate the web.  But if the user wants to use the feature then there is little reason to stop him.  If you want to *know* that it is a URL then you need to present a different UI gadget.  Something along the lines of a specific File + Open URL command and a text box that resembles the Address bar of a browser.

Comment: You could just delete any files that reside in the temp directory as you could assume that these where downloaded ones?

Comment: @MattWilko, I've said that in the question, but that's just not good programming.

Comment: @HansPassant. I agree, this seems to be something like broken UI. This component is the front end to several technologies from multiple generations, so it will not cover all cases. I've hoped I could do something about it from .NET. The reason I'd like that is that FileOpenDialog is extensible by third parties and most extensions will be unable to hook into any custom solution of my own. Even wrapping [IFileOpenDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775834(v=vs.85).aspx) myself doesn't seem to provide a solution.

Comment: Although this is an interesting question. Unless the files are very large or there will be a lot of them, it is probably not a big concern.

Comment: Not really an answer, but what about checking create datetime as a proxy for "just downloaded?"  Then - at least you would know that the file was literally "just added" to the system.

Answer (score 1):

There's no obvious way to do this, but as a workaround, how about checking where the file lives? It looks like by default this dialog downloads files to the users Temporary Internet Files directory, so you could introduce some code that looks something like this:

```
FileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{

    string temporaryInternetFilesDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(temporaryInternetFilesDir) && 
                dialog.FileName.StartsWith(temporaryInternetFilesDir, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        // the file is in the Temporary Internet Files directory, very good chance it has been downloaded...
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, just realised I entered the answer in C#, hope you can translate ok :)

Comment: Also, I've just noticed that you have already said this in the question, apologies all round :/